# Need to manually enable wireless networking on a Centrino N 6200

Tags: 11.04, networking, wireless, intel-wireless

When I run Ubuntu automatic connected to wireless network but cannot connect to Internet till I do Disable then enable networking,

Please I need solution for this issue, Help.

I get this output when I run `lspci`:

---

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 05)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 05)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GT218 [GeForce 310M] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 (rev 35)
03:00.0 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller
03:00.1 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd Memory Stick Host Controller
03:00.3 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd FireWire Host Controller
03:00.4 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

---

I get this output when I run `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 045e:00e1 Microsoft Corp. Wireless Laser Mouse 6000 Reciever
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0489:e00f Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ca:18b7 Ricoh Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:1001 Upek 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

---

I get this output when I run `sudo lshw -class Network`

```
 *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 35
       serial: 00:23:14:ea:2e:98
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlagn driverversion=2.6.38-10-generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:44 memory:dd100000-dd101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Atheros Communications
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: c0
       serial: 00:24:be:ea:64:04
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.0-NAPI firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:45 memory:db100000-db13ffff ioport:4000(size=128)
```

---

I get this output when I run `rfkill list all`

0: hci0: Bluetooth Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no 1: phy0: Wireless LAN Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no

Comment: is this an acer laptop by any chance? If it is, does this question and answer help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/54879/wireless-on-acer-laptop-is-disabled/54918#54918

Comment: No it's Vaio laptop

Comment: please add to your question the output of `rfkill list all` immediately after boot - i.e. when your network is disabled.

Comment: FYI: The card is this (from their `lspci`): `02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 (rev 35)`

Comment: So. what can I do. pleas I need help it's difficult to do this process every time

Answer (score 1):

I unfortunately don't have an answer but have the exact same problem on my Vaio laptop with a WiMax 6250 wifi adapter.  I've found lately I have to remove the SSID and its configuration and re-add, then it starts working.  Otherwise I get an IP address from the router that's valid but can't ping, check a route, etc..  Nothing.  I think its a bug but can't pinpoint it yet.

Answer (score 0):

(This is a total guess)

Try installing the new driver backports, sometimes a fix from a driver will be backported to a stable release. Install this package (or just click on the link):

[linux-backports-modules-cw-2.6.39-natty-generic](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/linux-backports-modules-cw-2.6.39-natty-generic)

Then reboot and see if that helps.